# How to reference an array method within a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods

```
var myList = ["Hello There World", "meatball", "cookie monster"];

var BreakUpFirst = function (myList) {
document.write(myList[0].split(" "));
};
```

Hello I am new to JavaScript so please bear with me. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I am trying to break the first string in the `myList` array into its own array with 3 values.  The split method works fine for me outside of the function, but I can't get it to work inside. I want to create `BreakUpFirst` as a new array and keep `myList` or any other array I pass through it as is.

Comment: Why not just `var BreakUpFirst = myList[0].split(" ");`?

Comment: you're not executing the function - you're just defining one. you'd need `BreakUpFirst()` afterwards somewhere to actually RUN the code...

Comment: Still getting an error when I run the code after. I am trying to learn how to pass arrays through functions and would like the array to be the argument of the function.

JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined on line 5

Comment: That's because you have to pass in your array the way you've defined your function.  If you want to use the global `myList` array you've already defined, take `myList` out of your function definition so it just reads `var BreakUpFirst = function() {`   
  
Alternative, you can invoke your function as indicated in my answer below, passing in the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually doing a couple of different things here.  If you just want to assign the value of `myList[0].split(" ")` to `var BreakUpFirst`, then the solution suggested by @thefourtheye is ideal.  Just assign the value directly:

```
var BreakUpFirst = myList[0].split(" ");
```

If you're trying to use a function that will always break up a string stored at the first element of an array and output it to the screen, then you need to make sure you pass in the array as a parameter.  If you define your function:

```
 var BreakUpFirst = function(myList) {
     return myList[0].split(" ");
 }

 var myList = ["Hello There World", "meatball", "cookie monster"];
```

You need to make sure you invoke the function and **pass in the parameter**:

```
 var brokenString = BreakUpFirst(myList);
 alert(brokenString);
```

You will get an alert box with the `brokenString` array, `"Hello","There","World"`

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but I am still getting `undefined` in the alert box. Was hoping to get "There" in a pop up for `alert(brokenString[1]);` Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3211495: The problem is the use of `document.write()`. That should just be a return. I've edited the answer since it seems pretty clear that's what citizenslave meant to be there.